# Is there an easy way to find angle between 2 lines in openCV python?

Tags: python, opencv, line

Im trying to properly detect rhombus and square, so what im doing is drawing diagonals in both. Also i put a line (green line) in top so i can calculate angle between this line and diagonals to compare. But is there any easy way to do it? I cant find any.

both lines are drawn by cv2.line(....,...,.) function

---

Green line:

```
cv2.line(img,(0,10),(img.shape[1], 10), (0,255,0),3)
```

---

Diagonal:

```
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(countour)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.int0(box)
        im = cv2.drawContours(img, [box], 0, (0,0,255), 2)

        cv2.line(img,(box[2][0],box[2][1]),(box[0][0],box[0][1]), (255,0,0),2)
```

[This is the output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sTXS.png)

Answer (score 0):

[atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function should be useful there. Please look first at drawing in linked article. As you might note it allow finding angle between horizontal line and line which span between origin point and certain point (x, y). This might be easily adopted to any line for which ends coords are known - if you have line (x1,y1)-(x2,y2) just compute `x = x2-x1` and `y = y2-y1` and feed them into [math.atan2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.atan2) which will return angle in radians. Next you have to process values you will get from atan2 for your lines. You might simply subtract lesser from bigger to get one of correct values (note that if you have two perpendicular lines that result in angle which might be described as `0.5*pi` or `1.5*pi`)